# Data cardinality is ambiguous: Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples. Image classififcation model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to train a machine learning image classification model however i keep recieving a value error.

This is the code

```
model.compile(
  optimizer="adam",
  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train), epochs=5, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

The error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/hc/jd3r3_g12355379n5gx9cy7m0000gn/T/ipykernel_18704/2140074756.py in <module>
      3   loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      4   metrics=['acc'])
----> 5 history = model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train), epochs=5, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1958             )
   1959         msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1960         raise ValueError(msg)
   1961 
   1962 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96
  y sizes: 308
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

However when i print the length of each array i am using they are all the same size?

```
print(len(y_train))
3693
```

```
print(len(X_train))
3693
```

The shape of both produce:

```
np.array(X_train).shape
(3693, 96, 96, 3)

np.array(y_train).shape
(3693,)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: "*when i print the length of each array*" - please update your post to include explicitly the code used for checking this, along with the obtained results. Include also a sample of your `X_train` and `y_train`. See how to create a [mre].

Comment: What 'length'?  The `shape`?  `np.array(Xtrain).shape`, `np.array(ytrain).shape`?

Comment: np.array(X_train).shape
(3693, 96, 96, 3)
ape
np.array(y_train).shape
(3693,)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post to show you the shape of both numpy arrays. They are different as you both expected

Comment: See what your model.fit expects when one input `n` 'images' (3d arrays), and the other is a 1d array of 'identifiers' (categories)?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the shape of the y is 1D. you can pass it like this :

```
np.array(y_train).reshape((-1,1))
```

Then see if the error is gone or not.